# PHP delete multiple table rows using checkbox

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've seen a few questions here already about this topic but I can't see a solution to what I'm trying to do.  I have a table and I want to be able to check a checkbox next to each row to have a multiple delete function.  I've placed a delete button above the table.

My delete button:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="staff_list_submit" name="multi_delete" value="Delete"
           onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to do that?')">
</form><br>
```

My TD containing the checkbox:

```
        <td style="width: 60px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['staff_id']; ?>"></td>
```

My PHP code to handle the delete:

```
if(isset($_POST['multi_delete']))
{
     $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
     for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
        echo $del_id;
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM `Tom`.`staff_details` WHERE `staff_id`=`$del_id`;");
        $result = $stmt->execute();
    }

    if($result) {
        exit(header('Location: staff_multiple_delete.php'));
    }
}
```

I try to echo `$del_id` and nothing comes back.

I do get two errors on screen when I click on the Delete button:

```
Undefined index: checkbox
Undefined index: result
```

I have been pulling my hair out over this, if there's any help available it would be appreciated. I'm still new to PHP

Thanks

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Where you have n element called `Checkbox` in your form?

Comment: Where did `$_POST['checkbox']` came from?

Comment: checkbox comes form the name of the my input checkbox. Second code snippet.  The prepared statements will be added later, I'm just trying to get some working code first.

Answer (score 0):

It's not tested but I think you ought to be able to do something like the following rather than a loop as you had - which sort of misses the point of prepared statements due to the repeated `prepare`

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['checkbox'] ) ){

    $ids = implode( ',', $_POST['checkbox'] );
    $sql='delete from `tom`.`staff_details` where `staff_id` in ( :ids )';
    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){
        $stmt->bindParam( ':ids', $ids );
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi RamRaider, I gave it a go but it doesn't seem to recognise that the checkbox has been selected. All examples I've seen have suggested that layout for the checkbox.